# Get initialVisibilityDelay CloudMessage

Tags: azure, queue, azure-queues

I have a message in queue with initialVisibilityDelay property (so, message is not visible now):

```
await inputQueue.AddMessageAsync(new CloudQueueMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queueItem)), null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(retryMinutes), null, null);
```

Any way to get this message to do some actions with the message with some conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the visibility delay has expired you can only delete it and all other messages.

It is hidden from any gets or peeks.  This is an agent-centric mechanism for scheduling.

Comment: `you can only delete it and all other messages` - Would you mind explaining how?

Comment: Sure.  In the `CloudQueue` class there's a `Clear()` method.  It relates to this API operation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/clear-messages

Comment: Thanks. But how clearing messages help in OP's case? It will remove all messages from the queue which may not be the desired behavior.

Comment: It may be useful to some...others, not.

Answer (score 1):

> Any way to get this message to do some actions with the message with
>   some conditions?

Unfortunately no. This message will remain hidden for that duration and can't be fetched. You will only be able to do anything with this message when it appears in the queue i.e. after the visibility timeout period has expired.